# DAX number of days

Tags: dax

Can you please help how I can return the total number of days for each month in a given quarter?
For example, I already have 92 days for December 2025 but how can I show 92 days for October and November as well?

[image: See example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only a count, you can use measure:

```
QuarterDays = calculate(countrows(VALUES('Calendar'[Date])), FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), selectedvalue('Calendar'[Year]) = 'Calendar'[Year] && selectedvalue('Calendar'[Quarter]) = 'Calendar'[Quarter] ))
```

Comment: So far I used New Columns instead of Measures, is there a way to solve  this with a new column?

Comment: if you want a New Columns, then we need to change this statement a little.

QuarterDays =
var _year = ('Calendar'[Year]) 
var _quarter = ('Calendar'[Quarter])
return
 calculate(countrows(VALUES('Calendar'[Date])), FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),  _year  = 'Calendar'[Year] &&  _quarter  = 'Calendar'[Quarter] ))